# use jquery to add event to a element based on href

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to trigger a javascript function when a specific URL is available on the page.

The url looks like:

I would like to use jQuery to detect the url and launch an event.

I have come this far:

```
$( 'a[href="https://www.mypage.com/my-page/details.jsp"]' ).bind( "click", function() {
    alert( "yoehoe" );
});
```

But it doesn't trigger the alert on a click. on the specific href. Can anyone help me on this one?

Comment: you should wrap it with `doc ready`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap the code in `document.ready` to ensure that event gets bind to respective elements once they are there on page.like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $( 'a[href="https://www.mypage.com/my-page/details.jsp"]' ).bind( "click", function() {
   alert( "yoehoe" );
 });});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Pt9bh/)**

Alternatively, You can also use `.on()` with `.click` if dom is generated dynamically.like this:

```
$(document).on("click",'a[href="https://www.mypage.com/my-page/details.jsp"]',function()     {
 alert( "yoehoe" );
});
```